# Рекурсивный подзапрос: доступ к внешнему алиасу

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется некая таблица с иерархическими данными (коды ОКАТО) и есть такой запрос:

```
select ...,
       e.idOKATO,
       ...
  from MyEntity e
```

Теперь возникло требование — выводить не id иерархической сущности, а id некого ее предка (в дереве). Я написал такой рекурсивный запрос:

```
select okato.id
  from ( select o.id
           from MyOkato o
        connect by (prior o.idParent = o.id and length(o.sCode) >= 5)
          start with o.id = :idOKATO
          order by rownum desc) okato
 where rownum = 1
```

Он работает как нужно — при подстановке вместо `:idOKATO` id потомка, выводит id нужного мне предка.

Но, теперь, при вносе этого запроса в качестве подзапроса в первый:

```
select ...,
       (select okato.id
          from ( select o.id
                   from MyOkato o
                connect by (prior o.idParent = o.id and length(o.sCode) >= 5)
                  start with o.id = e.idOKATO
                  order by rownum desc) okato
         where rownum = 1) as idOKATO,
       ...
  from MyEntity e
```

возникает ошибка:

> ORA-00904: "E"."IDOKATO": недопустимый идентификатор

Как исправить?

Comment: если вот тут `start with o.id = e.idOKATO` вместо `e.idOKATO` поставить какое-то значение - запрос работает?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, да, работает. Получается внешние алиасы доступны только на глубине вложенности не более 1. Удалось избавиться от одного уровня и запрос заработал. См. ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось избавиться от одного уровня вложенности таким образом:

```
select ...,
       ( select o.id
           from MyOkato o
          where length(o.sCode) <= 5
        connect by prior o.idParent = o.id and length(o.sCode) >= 5
          start with o.id = e.idOKATO) as idOKATO,
       ...
  from MyEntity e
```

Запрос заработал. Заодно избавился и от ненужной сортировки.

Comment: В таком виде остается возможность получить `ORA-01427`, если подзапрос вернет больше одной строки. Если у вас данные устроены так, что это невозможно, то ОК, а если нет, добавьте агрегатную функцию в подзапрос, или соедините подзапрос с `MyEntity` через `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Код родительского элемента заведомо короче, чем у дочернего, поэтому когда очередной полученный элемент будет иметь код длиной не более 5, итерации прекратятся